# Is java.awt.Graphics outdated?

Tags: java, windows, graphics, awt

Hey Java workers has Graphics been replaced by a new package? I saw a Graphics2D class and started wondering if there has been any recent update to the way Java handles graphics? Are we still using any older packages as of Windows 11?

Comment: Short answer is yes and no.  `Graphics` is the core stone for AWT and Swing, `Graphcis2D` extends from `Graphics` and where possible you should use it.  In most places that Swing passes `Graphics`, you can safely cast it to `Graphics2D`.  The reason I'm saying "yes" is because you should probably be considering using JavaFX instead

Comment: Recap of MadProgrammer: (1) wherever you encounter `Graphics` (used by the swing GUI) you may cast it to `Graphics2D`. (An awkward backward compatibility introduced very early.)  (2) JavaFX aka OpenJFX is a vast improvement over swing (code + UI), (3) swing is still in heavy use, not outdated.

Comment: Which Java packages are and are not outdated does not have anything to do with the version of Windows that you are using.

Comment: @MadProgrammer (A) Did you mean “no” rather than “yes” in last sentence? (B) Seems like your Comment would make a good Answer.

Comment: Re (B) Well yea ... maybe.   But this does smell of an opinion-based question.  (What do you mean by "outdated"?  Even Joop's "swing is still in heavy use, not outdated" is a statement of opinion, not an inference.  The fact that something is still heavily used doesn't *mean* it is not outdated.  Consider the internal combustion engine ...)

Comment: No, I mean AWT and Swing are outdated and you should consider out of date generally